# JavaFX TableView `Show Columns` button overlaps very right column header

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, xmltable

Got a little problem with the JavaFX `TableView`, the button at the top right, if enabled, it overlaps with the very right column header.

[image: Faulty JavaFX TableView]

I don't apply any css to the table whatsoever.

Here is the FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="serverTable" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity"
    minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnHostname" sortable="true" text="Hostname"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnPlayers" maxWidth="66.0" minWidth="66.0" sortable="true" text="Players"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnMode" minWidth="80.0" sortable="true" text="Mode"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnLanguage" minWidth="80.0" sortable="true" text="Language"/>
        <TableColumn maxWidth="65.0" minWidth="65.0" sortable="true" text="Version"/>
    </columns>
    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
    </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

Removed the irrelevant parts (cellValueFactories and such).

Anyways, I have struggled a little with the sizes of the single cells anyways and resizing is weird as well, might it be because of the sizes I am setting?
I have already tried around a little, but didn't manage to make the table like I want to.

Resizing the TableView after its loaded causes the cells to size more correctly, eg. the button isn't overlapping the very right column header anymore.

Comment: Why don't the `TableColumn` names line up with the cells? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: This seems as if either you are doing something strange with custom row or cell factories, or else you encountered a rare render/layout bug. In any case a [mcve] will be immensely helpful.